# Can I get value from JSONObject without mention its name?

Tags: java, json, org.json

My JSONObject:

```
{MyJSON:[{"id":"1","name":"panji","price":"100"}]}
```

I do this to get value of id:

```
menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
```

Can I get the value of id, name or price, without mentioning its name, may be like index or another method?

Comment: What's wrong with mentioning the name? Are you facing issues with that?

Answer (score 10):

You can call [`names()`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html#names) on a `JSONObject` to get a `JSONArray` of the names of its elements - this would let you do logic on them or retrieve their corresponding values dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Never knew there is a `names` method for `JSONObject` and I has been wasting hours trying to use `Iterator`

Comment: **404
Not Found**

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the attributes of a JSONObject like this

```
for(Iteraor key=jsonObject.keys();itr.hasNext();) {
   jsonObject.get(key.next());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use an `Iterator` with the for-each syntax, as annoying as that is. AFAIK it only works with `Iterable`s and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
for(Iterator<String> keys=obj.keys();keys.hasNext();) {
    obj.get(keys.next());
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it answers the question?